# Can not validate the AuthForm

Tags: python, django, forms, authentication, validation

I'm developing the Login view of my app, in order to do that I used the Django's built-in authentication form, but when I try to validate the form it returns False and I don't know why. I let here my code...

**models.py**

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    '''
    Model that represents a user in the database
    '''
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False, blank=False)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False, blank=False)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False, blank=False, unique=True)
    email = models.EmailField(null=False, blank=False, unique=True)
    password1 = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    password2 = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    birthday = models.DateField(null=False, blank=False)
    verified = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.first_name}: {self.email}'
```

**forms.py**

```
class AuthForm(AuthenticationForm):
    '''
    Form that uses built-in AuthenticationForm to handel user auth
    '''
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True,
        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={
            'placeholder': 'Correo electrónico', 
            'name': 'email', 
            'type': 'email', 
            'class': 'form-control'
        }))
    password1 = forms.CharField(max_length=25, required=True,
        widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={
            'placeholder': 'Contraseña', 
            'name': 'password1', 
            'type': 'password', 
            'class': 'form-control'
        }))

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('email','password1', )
```

**login.html**

```
                            <form action="{% url 'users:login' %}" method="post">
                                {% csrf_token %}
                                <div class="mb-3">{{ form.email }}</div>
                                <div class="mb-3">{{ form.password1 }}</div>
                                <div class="mb-3"><button class="btn btn-primary shadow d-block w-100" type="submit">Iniciar sesión</button></div>
                                <p class="text-muted">Recuperar contraseña</p>
                            </form>
```

**views.py**

```
def login_page(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':

        form = AuthForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            email = form.cleaned_data.get('email')
            password = form.cleaned_data.get('password1')

            user = authenticate(request, username=email, password=password)
            
            if user is not None:
                login(request, user)
                return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('network:profile'))
            else:
                return render(request, 'users/login.html', {'form': form})
        else:
            return render(request, 'users/login.html', {'form': form})

    return render(request, 'users/login.html', {
        'form': AuthForm(),
    })
```

The error occurs in form.is_valid(), it returns False even when I'm sure that I'm introducing valid data to the form. Is there some error(s) in my code?, I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something to consider if you're trying to use `email` for authentication.

Django is expecting to see a `username` value in the AuthForm. You can get around this by overriding the default Auth User Model.

Ensure you've specified your email field as the username in your `User` model then follow the guide found using the link below.

Follow this guide:
https://koenwoortman.com/python-django-email-as-username/

---

Additionally, you're going to have issues with using `password1` and `password2` as Django auth expects a `password` field when authenticating the user object.

I would remove `password1` and `password2` and just use the default `password` field otherwise you'll have to override/rewrite the default authentication/password methods used by Django to reference `password1` and `password2` when performing a login.

Your model will then look something like this:

```py
class User(AbstractUser):
    '''
    Model that represents a user in the database
    '''
    
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email' # add this

    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False, blank=False)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False, blank=False)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False, blank=False, unique=True)
    email = models.EmailField(null=False, blank=False, unique=True)
    birthday = models.DateField(null=False, blank=False)
    verified = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.first_name}: {self. Email}'
```

You'll also have to replace your auth form, template and views. to use the updated fields of 'email' and 'password'

Be sure to migrate changes to your user model if neccessary.

Answer (score -1):

I think you most use  form = AuthForm(request) instead of using form = AuthForm(request.POST)
because request.POST return form method and not data to validation

Comment: I proved that but does not work :(

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).